# Jasmine - How to chain a `.then` and a `.finally` in a callFake spy?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, promise, jasmine

I have the following function, that does a service call with a promise and a `.finally`:

```
myService.getStuff().then(function() {
   this.doStuffWhenServiceOK();
}, function () {
   this.doStuffWhenServiceFails();
}).finally(function() {
   this.doFinally();
});
```

I am spying on this service with the following spy:

```
spyOn(myService, 'getStuff').and.callFake(function() {
   return {
     then: function (succesFn, errorFn) {
       return succesFn();
     }
   };
});
```

The problem is that the test complains that the `.finally` is not known. Just adding it after `.then` does not seem to be a solution...

```
return {
  then: function(successFn) { 
    return successFn();
  },
  finally: function(successFn) {
    return successFn();
  }
}
```

Who knows how to chain `.then` and `.finally` in the `callFake` spy?

I work with Angular 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return a finally function.

```
function then(succesFn, errorFn) {
    succesFn(); 
    return {finally:function() {}};
}
```